# How to set apache make `127.0.0.1/mydoc` show my desired webpage instead of `127.0.0.1`?

Tags: virtualhost, apache2

THe project structure.

```
tree  /var/www/html/mydoc
/var/www/html/mydoc
├── build
│   ├── doctrees
│   └── html
│       ├── index.html
│       ├── _sources
│       │   ├── index.txt
│       ├── _static
├── make.bat
├── Makefile
└── source
    ├── conf.py
    ├── index.rst
    ├── _static
    ├── _templates
```

Notice:`index.html` located in `var/www/html/mydoc/build/html/index.html`.
My apache was build on debian ,not centos.

```
sudo cat  /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mydoc.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydoc/build/html
<Directory /var/www/html/mydoc/build/html>
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now input `127.0.0.1` can show the content in the `/var/www/html/mydoc/build/html/index.html` properly,in current setting,`127.0.0.1/mydoc` will show :

```
The requested URL /mydoc/ was not found on this server.
```

My requirement:

1.keep the `mydoc`s directory tree unchanged
2.Let `127.0.0.1/mydoc` show `/var/www/html/mydoc/build/html/index.html` properly.

How to set my apache to achieve the target?

Answer (score 2):

You could create an [Alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias):

```
Alias /mydoc /var/www/html/mydoc/build/html
```

This maps path `/mydoc` to your `DocumentRoot` with the effect that http://127.0.0.1/mydoc and http://127.0.0.1 show the same content.